# Move every alternate row of a pandas dataframe to a new column without NaN

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    A   B
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   a
3   4   b
4   5   a
5   6   b
6   7   a
7   8   b
8   9   a
9   10  b
```

I want to convert this into a new dataframe that has 2 columns - "a" and "b" with the corresponding row values as columns something like this:

```
a   b
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   5   6
3   7   8
4   9   10
```

I tried using the pivot function. While the values did move into the new column, the spaces were replaced by NaN. What is the correct way to do this?

```
df.pivot(columns="B", values = "A")

Output:
B   a   b
0   1.0 NaN
1   NaN 2.0
2   3.0 NaN
3   NaN 4.0
4   5.0 NaN
5   NaN 6.0
6   7.0 NaN
7   NaN 8.0
8   9.0 NaN
9   NaN 10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a counter :

```
(df.assign(counter=df.groupby("B").cumcount())
   .pivot("counter", "B", "A")
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None )
 )
```

If you are willing to go into numpy, and you are sure, it is just a and b :

```
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.A.to_numpy(), newshape=(-1, 2)),
             columns=pd.unique(df.B))


    a   b
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   5   6
3   7   8
4   9   10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep what you're doing with your initial pivot, you can remove the nan values and reset the index and refill the column, not really recommended if the number of pivoted values are not equal:

```
import pandas as pd

A = [i for i in range(1, 11)]
B = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b",]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": A, "B": B})

df = df.pivot(columns="B", values = "A")


df["a"] = df["a"][~np.isnan(df["a"])].reset_index(drop=True)
df["b"] = df["b"][~np.isnan(df["b"])].reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.dropna()

print(df)
```

output:

```
B    a     b
0  1.0   2.0
1  3.0   4.0
2  5.0   6.0
3  7.0   8.0
4  9.0  10.0
```